# Order result items by other attribute than range key

Tags: sorting, amazon-dynamodb

i've been researching a lot but I couldn't find the right answer/example.

In dynamodb I have table 'user_playlists' with hash key 'user_id' and range key 'playlist_id' (one user can have N playlists).

For each playlist I store information when playlist is created in an attribute 'created_ts' (I store timestamp of creation time). 'created_ts' is defined as index.

Now I query 'user_playlists' table to retrieve all playlists for particular user. Query is done with hash and range key.

Results are ordered by range key 'playlist_id' which is some hash, so order by that attribute means nothing to me. So I want to sort my results by attribute 'created_ts'.

Is it possible to sort by that indexed attribute with Query method? The existing logic of retrieving data by hash and range key should stay. I only want to add needed things to get ordered items by created time.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot sort with scan according to Amazon (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=328982#). Additionally, you cannot sort with query with any field, as you stated in your question.

Anyway, you can sort the results locally, I am doing that with the sortBy included in the underscore library. It is not the best solution, but it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you'll need to create a `LocalSecondaryIndex` with exactly the `RANGE` attribute you want to use to do the sort.

If you are querying with both the `HASH` and `RANGE` you won't get a list of playlists you'll get a single one, so your question is a little confusing.  If you want to find playlists by the `created_ts` field your best bet is to create a `LocalSecondaryIndex` with the `HASH` being the `user_id` and the `RANGE` being `created_ts`.